# The existence of convergent subsequences

Tags: convex-optimization

Considering an optimization problem on an infinite-dimensional Euclidean space, the sequence of objective functions is $J_{n}(\theta_{n})=||f(X,\theta_{n})-Y||^{2} $, where X and Y are datas.
This can yield a minimizing subsequence. How should I prove that this sequence has a convergent subsequence?You can make appropriate assumptions about ( f ).